# Расстановка ударений в поэтической речи

Tags: поэзия, орфоэпия

Возможно, уважаемое сообщество уже обратило внимание на мою попытку создания [компьютерной программы](http://www.ritminme.ru/o-programme/kratkoe) проверки ритмичности стихов. При её эксплуатации я столкнулся с проблемой: как не чуждым поэзии, но давно покинувшим школьную парту людям объяснить расстановку ударений в некоторых сомнительных ситуациях? Во всяком случае, со служебными словами и потерей ударения знаменательными словами без знания теории не разберёшься. Конечно, можно порекомендовать проговаривать такие стихи вслух – но сколько есть стихов, чудесно читающихся их авторами, но отвратительно – другими читателями! Обмануться так легко...

В общем, к программе требуется присовокупить кратенькую справку на этот счёт. Прошу знающих людей подсказали дилетанту: 
а) всё ли (и верно ли) я указал; 
б) сможет ли это понять неспециалист.

---

Хотя всякое словарное слово, имеющее хоть одну гласную, имеет и ударение, но поэтическая речь близка к живой речи. Поток живой речи русского языка состоит из фонетических слов. Фонетическое слово состоит из знаменательного слова (несущего ударение) и примыкающих к нему безударных (энклитики – спереди, проклитики – сзади).

Односложное служебное слово, как правило, безударно. Слабоударяемыми могут быть так же: 
1) простые числительные в сочетании с существительным;
2) глаголы "быть" и "стать", употребляемые, как связки;
3) "было" в значении прерванности или несовершения действия, выраженного сказуемым;
4) "бывало" в значении повторявшегося действия, выраженного сказуемым;
5) вводные слова "стало быть", "так сказать", "говорит";
6) "брат", употребленное в качестве обращения.

Существительное может передавать ударение предлогу. Обычно это связано с устаревшим местным падежом (пример - "на' море"), тогда, как в современном предложном этого не происходит ("на мо'ре").

Но в конце поэтической строки слово ударно всегда – поэтому популярна запись стихов "лесенкой".

Ударение может привнести:

1) логическое ударение в фразе;
2) формирование фонетического слова целиком из слов, обычно несущих служебную функцию; 
3) обособление знаками препинания.

---

Буду благодарен, если подскажут так же какие-нибудь признаки фонетического слова или законы его формирования.

---

А как вам такое еретическое утверждение, что с ударениями работает правило, аналогичное проверке написания вместе/раздельно: если соседние слова образуют некую "новую сущность", то и читаются они вместе, с одним ударением ("луч со'лнца", "мир ино'й")?

[[@DocentI](/users/508/docenti)](/users/508/docenti)
Спасибо за информацию по Колмогорову. Но тогда любое односложное слово можно пихать куда угодно в ямбе или хорее, и ритмичность от этого не пострадает... Надо поднабрать статистики. Просмотрел то, что у меня проанализировано из Пушкина... Избегал он подобных ситуаций, но парочка таких спондеев нашлась. 
"Днём **свет** Божий затмевает" - "///---/-" вместо "/-/-/-/-"
"Я там был; **мёд**, пиво пил" - "/-///-/" вместо "/-/-/-/"
В обоих случаях спондей действительно на ритмичность не влияет.

> Но разве "Мой" - служебное слово?

За что купил... Во всяком случае, Ф. И. Буслаев так считал... Это – как раз момент, который бы я хотел уточнить, т.к. не лингвист, а здесь что ни термин – то защищённая диссертация. А то и не одна. И сплошь – с разным толкованием терминов. Написать "односложные второстепенные члены предложения"? С местоимениями ясно, с числительными – оговорено, с прилагательными, глаголами и существительными – нет.

> При чтении это ударение нивелируется, подстраивается под ритм.

Что воспринимается, как безударное – таки да. А вот какую причину указать – пока в недоумении.

---

[[@behemothus](/users/445/behemothus)](/users/445/behemothus)

> если с двудольными метрами все нормально

А что, сними всё нормально? В двусложных размерах не бывает сбоев ритма?
Если обозначать ударные слоги как "/", а безударные – как "-", то имеем:
"/-"  - хорей; "-/"  - ямб; "--"  - пиррихий; "//"  - спондей.

Стихотворными размерами являются только два первых – два следующих являются отклонениями от размера. К пиррихиям отношение лучше – иногда даже говорят об "искусстве работы с пиррихиями", а часть теоретиков не признаёт пеоны №1-4 (4-сложные размеры) полноправными стихотворными размерами, поскольку они могут быт выражены сочетанием стопы ямба или хорея с пиррихием.

Спондеи так просто не прощаются. Сейчас у меня есть три версии, объясняющие, почему слово, которое вроде бы должно иметь ударение, в стихотворной строке двусложного размера его не проявляет:
1) односложное слово является "служебным в широком смысле" (так реализовано в программе);
2) по Колмогорову – потому, что односложное;
3) потому, что входит в фонетическое слово в качестве проклитики/энклитики.

Из 3-сложных размеров программа "знает" шесть: "/--" - дактиль, "--/" - анапест, "-/-" - амфибрахий, "-//" - бакхий, "//-" - антибакхий, "/-/" - амфимакр.  Озвученное Вами мнение Г.А.Шенгели по поводу хороших отношений дактиля и анапеста с  амфимакром мне очень понравилось. Оно очень хорошо объясняет, почему некоторые из проанализированных мною стихов, написанных дактилем или анапестом, превосходно читаются, хотя пестрят пометками сверхсхемных ударений по схеме амфимакра. Выкачал "Технику стиха" Г.А.Шенгели – почитаю.

Answer (score 5):

Вы рассматриваете, как я понимаю, случаи пропуска ударений, которые "ожидаются" в слове. Но разве это обязательно связано со смыслом?

Мои познания в этой сфере ограничиваются статьей в журнале "Квант", в которой излагались, насколько я помню, взгляды А.Н.Колмогорова на ритмику стиха. Так вот, там просто говорилось, что "лишнее", не укладывающееся в ритм ударение может стоять в слове, которое целиком умещается между двумя ударными слогами. Для двусложных ритмов это односложные слова, для трехсложных - могут быть и двусложные.

Мой дя-дя са-мых чест-ных пра-вил
 ' | !  -  | !  -  |  !  -  |  !  - |  
Ког-да не в шут-ку за-не-мог
 -  ! | - |  !  -  | -   -   !  |

Здесь восклицательным знаком показаны "законные" ударения, а апострофом - "лишние", которые не читаются.

Слово "Мой" имеет ударение, не нужное по схеме ямба. Но разве "Мой" - служебное слово? Просто короткое. При чтении это ударение нивелируется, подстраивается под ритм.
Думаю, есть и более яркие примеры, это то, что всплыло в сознании.

А вот во второй строке, наоборот, одно "ямбовое" ударение пропущено: в слове "занемог", которое, будучи трехсложным, не может уместиться в двусложной стопе. И, конечно, слово "не" ударение потеряло, но это соответствует подходу автора.

Если в строке много подобных отклонений, ее трудно отнести ктому или иному ритму. Однако, пользуясь формальными правилами, это сделать можно.

Вот условный (малохудожественный) пример:
Да, в по-ле вы-рос-ли ма-ки
 ! | ' - | ! - - | ! - |

Можно считать, что это дактиль, поэтому при чтении слова "в поле" практически потеряют свое ударение.Однако (по Колмогорову) это не противоречит определению дактиля, та как "в поле" целиком умещается между двумя "правильными" ударениями.

Comment: Извините, что не отвечаю по цепочке...
Новичок на вашем сайте очень ограничен в свободе словоизлияния.
Правлю исходный вопрос...

Comment: Нашла ту статью в "Кванте", №2, 1988. Можно скачать в формате .djvu [отсюда](http://www.kvant.info/arch/1988_2.htm)  
Можно найти и в формате .htm [здесь](http://vivovoco.rsl.ru/VV/Q_PROJECT/HEAP/88_02_1/88_02_11.HTM)

Comment: Спасибо. Материал есть.
Например, вот это: http://www.biometrica.tomsk.ru/kolmogorov/kolmogor11.htm

Comment: Посмотрела статью, это о другом. Во-первых, обзор, а во вторых, с упором на вероятностные модели и, особенно, на методологические проблемы. У Фукса же популярное изложение некоей формализации не претендующее, конечно, на полное исследование проблемы.  
В частности, даже если "лишние" ударения могут возникнуть сверх схемы, т.е. модель Колмогорова их не запрещает, это не значит, что такой стих будет художественным и качественным.  
Разве что сознательно использовать это как художественный прием.

Comment: То есть получается, весь список ТС-а - побоку?

Comment: Почему же? Мне же не модель какая абстрактная нужна - а список правил...  
Результат уже есть - мне не следует употреблять термин "служебное слово", поскольку доминирующая в настоящий момент школа использует его в более узком смысле. Возможно, придётся просто перечислить части речи, которые в потоке живой речи могут терять ударение.  
И термин "знаменательное" тоже под вопросом. Может, вообще не стоит морочить голову терминами людям с тонкой душевной организацией.  ;)

Answer (score 2):

Не очень понимаю, с какого боку тут Андрей Николаевич...
Если очень кратко. 
Применительно к русской силлабо-тонике для двусложных метров существуют т.н. спондей и пиррихий - стопа из двух ударных и двух безударных слогов соответвенно. Изначально применительно к ямбу, но потом распространилось и на хорей.
Иногда трактуют как вообще всякую стопу со сверсхемным ударением и "пустую", без требуемого схемой ударения, в т.ч. и для для трехсложных метров; равно как и сами слоги с таким ударением.

Так вот, если с двудольными метрами все нормально, то весь фокус в трехсложных. 
Здесь нет единого мнения, какие отступления от общего ритма можно не относить к перебоям. Общим является мнение, что за отступлениями не должен теряться определяющий ритм. Но дальше - все довольно смутно.

Так например, по Шенгели для дактиля и анапеста допустим "амфимакр" - т.е. дополнительное дактильное ударение в анапесте, и наоборот. Ударение же на второй слог в этих метрах считалось плохим. Пример DocentI при таком подходе был бы неудачным. 
Но такая трактовка, как и все остальные, не прижилась.

А вообще-то начните хотя бы с этого
http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D1%85%D1%81%D1%85%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%B5_%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B0%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5

Comment: Ну, я же не утверждаю, что это был именно Колмогоров, хотя он этими вопросами [интересовался](http://hojja-nusreddin.livejournal.com/2696543.html?thread=29417311) Жаль, нет под рукой той сноски на "Квант", номер журнала старый.

Comment: В ответ правлю исходный вопрос.

Comment: Нашла и просмотрела ту статью. (см. в комментах к моему ответу).   Точно, Колмогоров (с Прохоровым).

Comment: Да знаю я, что он что-то там пытался математизировать. А спрашивал, с какого боку его приплетать, коли речь идет о вещах, задолго до него сформулированных?! Классиком жанра он не стал, школы предметной не создал...  
Ссылку нашел на "Квант" с Дмитрием Борисовичем. Рад был узнать, что он здравствует и благополучно смыслся с Штаты ажно в 1990. Более ничего прокомментировать не могу. Гумилев ему явно не покорился...

Comment: Ну, все-таки какая ни на есть формализация. Я и не говорила, что схемой можно описать такое сложное явление, как стих.  
Просто в перечне автора мне показалось, что не все случаи разобраны. А почему? Будучи "Колмогоровскими", не соответствуют "художественности" стиха? Что делать, например, с такой строкой:  
> Сад дяди самых честных правил  

Уж "сад" то ни при каком определении не служебное слово. Так вот, возможна такая фраза в ямбе (пусть и не у Пушкина)?

Comment: Да дались Вам эти служебные слова... 
Это для тех, кто не понимает, что на предлоги в русском ударение обычно не падает. 
Все остальные слова рассматриваются как равноправные. 
И как допустимые рассматривается обычно либо внесхемное ударение либо полностью безударная стопа.

При этом должен соблюдаться «запрет переакцентуации». (Когда ударный слог слова приходится на слабую долю, безударные слоги не могут приходиться на смежное сильное место - Вики.) Все.  
Меня иногда  удивляет сколько велосипедов изобретают на пустом месте.

Comment: ОК. "Переакцентуацию" вношу в рекомендации.  

Не знаю, удастся ли сформулировать универсальную схему стиха, но правила для конкретной языковой ситуации (появления безударных слов) надеюсь подобрать.  

Как по мне, так для этого "саддяди" лучше всего подходит экспертное заключение из м/ф "Рататуй": "Это не отравлено, но я бы его не ел".  

Единичное внесхемное ударение - это всё-таки или поэтический брачок (у современников), или строго дозируемо применяемая приправа (у классиков).  

Не подскажете, где можно покопать в сторону фонетического слова? Этот подход мне кажется более перспективным.

Comment: "Это для тех, кто не понимает, что на предлоги в русском ударение обычно не падает."  

Так именно для таких инструкция и пишется, ибо дремучесть широких поэтических масс не поддаётся описанию.  :(

Answer (score 1):

> Так например, по Шенгели для дактиля и анапеста допустим "амфимакр"

Это который "советский поэт и филолог"?
А как же до него писали?

Comment: Не важно, как до него - важно, что подметил он. Почитаем...

Answer (score 1):

Где сама программа проверки?

Comment: В начале текста - ссылка. Или в любом поисковике наберите "Ритм во мне".

P.S. За полтора года набран некоторый опыт, в копилку которого вошли и результаты обсуждения на этом сайте. Программа подверглась некоторой систематизации, словарь (базирующийся на словаре А.А. Зализняка) был пополнен не совпадающими словами из словаря и В.В. Лопатина, был доработан рифмовник, добавлены словари для украинского языка. Ну и кой чего по мелочам.